# Converting celsius to fahrenheit using methods

Tags: java

So I am having a problem figuring out this celsius to fahrenheit with methods, Ive done tried to figure this problem out myself for days and ive thrown in the towel and need help.

Here is the code:

```
 public class ctof {
 public statice void main(string[]     args) {

for (double i = 40; i >= 30; i--) { 
     double j = 130;
     double x = celsiusToFahrenheit(0)
     double y = fahrenheitToCelsius(0)

   System.out.println(i + "  " + (x + i) + " |  " + (j + i) + "  " + (y + i)
}
 public static double         celsiusToFahrenheit(double celsius) {
 double fahrenheit = (5.0 / 9) * celsius + 32;

return fahrenheit;
}
  public static double     fahrenheitToCelsius(double fahrenheit) {
 double celsius = (9.0 / 5) * fahrenheit - 32;

return celsius;

 }
}
```

Note that for the numbers to decrement in the loop 1234 exe I have to group them in parentsies (lettet + letter and if I dont group them or attach them to an I they dont increment but stay stagnant.

Note 2: When I go to increment them by 10  they dont increment but only add 10 to where they start so instead of starting with 70 they do 60 or 70, not 70, 60 50... the way I need them to

When I do them in a non method everything is fine.

Can somebody tell me what im doing wrong and how to correct it, thank you.

Comment: `celsiusToFahrenheit(0)` are you sure that you always want to pass 0? Not `i`?

Comment: thank you tom i corrected that, i don t know how to give you +1